# exception #0 (reflectionexception): class lof\marketplace\model\source\approval does not exist

Tags: magento2

Delete the attribute of approval form the backend
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_id="201";

Answer (score 0):

When I deleted the attribute from the database using the following SQL query, the error has been solved:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_id = "<attribute id>";
```